# USB host recognition

Tags: embedded, usb, microcontroller, usb-mass-storage

I'm developing an embedded USB device which needs to be available to two different hosts.
The first is a normal PC, where it will be used as a MSC (mass storage) device, and the second is a specific hardware which the USB device needs to comunicate with a CDC profile.

during the enumeration, the USB device send descriptor table where it declares its capabilities.

Is there a way in the enumeration process to know to which host the device was connected to ?

Comment: Platform? Language? What have you tried?

Comment: @Niels it doesn't matter, it's a protocol question, but if you really want to know... Msp430f5529, C.

Comment: If you have control of the **specific hardware**, you can add an extra GPIO to its connector connected to GND/VBUS and pull in the opposite direction on the peripheral.  Then by reading the GPIO you can determine out of band the host type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution perhaps would be to implement a "USB Composite Device", where the single device presented both the MSC and CDC class interfaces simultaneously.  The host PC would see both interfaces, but you could simply leave one unused.  The "specific hardware" would probably simply ignore the MSC class if it had no support for it.

Comment: I thought of that, I just wanted to know if host information is also transferred during enumeration.

Comment: Not much - host identification is sometimes attempted by fingerprinting the sequence of operations performed by the host against a database of observed behavior.  In this case, you'd probably learn enough based on which of the interfaces actually gets used.  And it may be that with this approach you do not even need to "know" but rather it would just be only the code connected to the used interface which ever gets any data to work on.